# Permanently Disable Certain Object Data

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am working with the framework Clockwork HL2RP and struggling with creating an item, which is represented as an object:

```
>local ITEM = Clockwork.item:New();

>ITEM.name = "Citizen CID";

>ITEM.cost = 1;

>ITEM.model = "models/dorado/tarjetazero.mdl";

>ITEM.weight = 0;

>ITEM.access = "v";

>ITEM.useText = "Print Info";
>ITEM.description = "A small, plastic card with a blank side.";
```

...Et Cetera. Every item with any data within `ITEM.useText` automatically has a "use" button inserted onto it, activating the function OnUse.

```
ITEM:AddData("description", "A small, plastic card with a blank side.", true);
ITEM:AddQueryProxy("description", "description");
ITEM:AddData("useText", "Print Info", true);
ITEM:AddQueryProxy("useText", "useText");

function ITEM:OnUse(player, itemEntity)
local citizenCID = player:GetSharedVar("citizenID");
local citizenName = player:Name();
self:removeData("useText", “Print Info”);
self:SetData("description", "Name: "..citizenName.."\nCID: "..citizenCID.."\n\nA Citizen Identification Card filled with information.");
return false;
end;
```

This is what I have so far. However, I want the "useButton" to disappear after the user's info is printed on it. How would I do this?

Comment: Note, that the second part of the code is the point of focus, I'm trying to find a way to remove the query I've added so the framework will not recognize the item as a useable one anymore.

Comment: add a condition to "return false" on the button function itself